# オレはまだ死にたくねえんだ: what is たくねえ?

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations, slang, manga

I’d like to know what is たくねえ here? たく means “to cook” but I don’t think that’s it here. I suspect it’s slang for something but what?

Source:
https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/4/p/12

Answer (score 1):

Its simply a more masculine way of saying you dont want to do X, where X in this case is 死ぬ。死に＋たいー＞死にたくないー＞死にたくねぇ。When attached to the stem of a verb, ~たい means to want to do something, and it conjugates as an いーadjective.